# C++ Can't Access Private Class Variables Even from a Same Class Function

Tags: c++, class, private

So I'm working on a program which is a game of Blackjack. I have a class called Player for each player in the game. The problem lies in this block of code here which is inside Player.cpp:

```
void Player::SetFunds(int amt){
  cout << "setting funds:" << endl;
  cout << m_funds << "m_funds" << endl;
  m_funds = amt;
  cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

When compiled, I get a segmentation fault. The line "setting funds:" prints, but I cannot print m_funds, nor can I set it to amt (I tried it before adding the print statement for m_funds).

Here's the declaration of the function in Player.h (which is included in Player.cpp).

```
void SetFunds(int amt);
```

And here is where I have m_funds, among other private variables in the Player class.

```
 private:
  char* m_name;
  int m_funds;
  int m_bet;
  Hand m_hand;
  bool m_busted;
};
```

Is there something I'm missing? Why can't I seem to access a private Player class variable even though I am inside a Player class function? Is it possible the error is elsewhere even though I get a segmentation fault right after the "setting funds" prints?

Also, I can change the private variables in the constructor just fine, as follows:

```
Player::Player(char *name, int amt){
  m_name = name;
  cout << amt << endl; //Amount prints as 100
  m_funds = amt; // sets m_funds to 100
  cout << m_funds << endl; //m_funds prints as 100 just fine
  m_bet = 0;
  m_hand = Hand();
  m_busted = false;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is where I call the function SetFunds inside Blackjack.cpp:
(m_players is a vector of Players as a private variable of Blackjack class.) Again, amt couts to 100.

```
void Blackjack::SetPlayerFunds(int player, int amt){
  cout << amt << endl;
  m_players[player].SetFunds(amt);
}
```

And here is where I call that function from Project.cpp (which contains main):
(Note: This is for a project where I cannot edit this file and have to base my code around it)

```
Blackjack *CreateGame(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char **names;
  int *funds;
  int numPlayers;
  Blackjack *game;

  numPlayers = ProcessArgs(argc - 1, &argv[1], names, funds);

  game = new Blackjack(names, numPlayers);
  for (int p = 0; p < numPlayers; p++) {
    game->SetPlayerFunds(p, funds[p]);
}
```

EDIT 2:
Here is the Blackjack class constructor which is called inside Blackjack::CreateGame.

```
Blackjack::Blackjack(char *names[], int numPlayers){
  std::vector<Player> m_players;
  m_dealer = Player();

  int amt = 100;

  for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++){
    Player player(names[i], amt);
    m_players.push_back(player);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. The `this` pointer is probably null, i.e. you're calling a member function on an invalid object.

Comment: Debugger? Is there a program or something I can use? Also, what is a this pointer?

Comment: what happens if you `cout << m_bet` instead of `m_funds`? but just to make sure can you temporarily set `m_bet = 1` in the constructor instead of 0

Comment: I did that and I can't cout m_bet either. So it seems to be all of the private variables that I cannot access.

Comment: "segmentation fault" is a completely different thing to "cannot access". If you could not access a variable the compiler will give an error before you even run the program.

Comment: An IDE that compiles usually has a built in debugger.  It helps if you post info about the operating system and IDE or compiler that you are using.  It also helps if you actually post a small, compilable program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Try `cout << this << endl;` and see if it's null. Then learn to use a debugger.

Comment: _"So it seems to be all of the private variables that I cannot access."_ Have you actually tried printing any public variables? Or are you just leaping to the conclustion that it's related to `private`?

Comment: Can you update your question to show where you are calling set funds from?

Comment: I tried printing amt and it printed 100 as expected. My this was equal to 0. I'm sorry, I'm new to C++. What is 'this' and what does that mean if it is null?

Comment: It means you need to issue a _player = new Player( name, val );_ before calling functions!

Comment: I made an edit to show where I call SetFunds. And a second edit to show where I created the players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the Blackjack constructor.

```
Blackjack::Blackjack(char *names[], int numPlayers){
  std::vector<Player> m_players;
  m_dealer = Player();

  int amt = 100;

  for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++){
    Player player(names[i], amt);
    m_players.push_back(player);
  }
}
```

You are creating m_player on the heap in the constructor, assigning and adding players, but probably never initializing the real member of the same name in the class...

To solve the issue, remove the std::vector m_players;

Answer (score 0):

Umm, It seems that `this` pointer is strange..

I suggest this test code.

```
void Blackjack::SetPlayerFunds(int player, int amt)
{
  cout << amt << endl;

  // if "m_players" is std::vector
  m_players.at(player).SetFunds(amt);
  // elif "m_players" is C-array
  if (player >= sizeof(m_players)/sizeof(m_players[0]))
    abort(); // assert(false) or setting breakpoint will be better, if you can use debugger
  m_players[player].SetFunds(amt);
}
```

Comment: Well I changed it to the way you have it as "m_players.at(player).SetFunds(amt);" because I am using std:vector.

You are right that it fixed `this`. But now I get a different error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Abort

Comment: @seekerlite Yes, That is exactly what I say. `at()` throw `std::out_of_range` if `player >= m_players.size()`. I suggest insert `try { m_players.at(player).SetFunds(amt); } catch (std::out_of_range&) { std::cerr << "bug:" player << std::endl; }` into `SetPlayerFunds` if you can't use any debuggers. If you can use a debugger, your debugger may inform you when uncaught exception is thrown